# Flex 4: LineSeries AnimateColor not working

Tags: apache-flex, animation, graph, colors

This is a fairly simple question I would think.
here is the code (I cut it down for an easy read)

```
    <fx:Declarations>
    <s:AnimateColor id="rw" 
                    target="{targetRatioCol}"
                    colorFrom="0x000000" 
                    colorTo="0xFFFFFF"
                    colorPropertyName="color"
                    duration="5000" 
                    repeatCount="0" 
                    repeatBehavior="reverse"
                    />

</fx:Declarations>
....

            <mx:LineSeries id="targetRatio" displayName="Target" xField="Month" creationComplete="rw.play();" yField="targetRatio" verticalAxis="{v2}"
                       >
            <mx:lineStroke>
                <mx:SolidColorStroke id="targetRatioCol"   color="0xFFFFFF" weight="4"  />
            </mx:lineStroke>
        </mx:LineSeries>
```

the chart shows the line but the animation doesn't work.
My question is why isn't this working?

Thanks in advance
Nat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that the Chart redraws when the animation is played.  Charts are a very strange beast.  If I were you, I'd create an item renderer for the line which has the animation within it so that you'd only redraw the line.